# Query not working properly

Tags: mysql

What I want is if do not pass any values to the variable then it should show all the values from the table while if I pass a value to variable then it should data on filter of that parameter.

```
SET @groupname := 'MidasGoogleAppsUsers';
IF @groupname = '' THEN
SELECT t.GroupName AS GroupName, t.GroupName AS ApplicationName, t.UserName
FROM UserApplication t;

ELSE

SELECT t.GroupName AS GroupName, t.GroupName AS ApplicationName, t.UserName
    FROM UserApplication t
    WHERE t.GroupName = @groupname;

END IF;
```

Here is the table structure below:

```
CREATE TABLE userapplication
            (`ID` INT,
             `ApplicationName` VARCHAR(100),
             `GroupName` VARCHAR(100),
             `UserName` VARCHAR(100))
```

Comment: In what way is your current query not working properly?

Comment: What is happening that shouldn't (or not happening that should)

Comment: @Fiona= it gives me an error:  
Error Code : 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF @groupname = '' THEN
SELECT t.GroupName AS GroupName, t.GroupName AS Applicat' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
    SELECT t.GroupName AS GroupName, t.GroupName AS ApplicationName, t.UserName
    FROM UserApplication t
    WHERE @Groupname is null or @Groupname = '' or t.GroupName = @groupname;
```

You can do this with logic in the `where` clause.  You don't need `if` as all.

To add more conditions:

```
    SELECT t.GroupName AS GroupName, t.GroupName AS ApplicationName, t.UserName
    FROM UserApplication t
    WHERE (@Groupname is null or @Groupname = '' or t.GroupName = @groupname) and
          (@UserName is null or @UserName = '' or t.UserName= @UserName );
```

Comment: I tried in like this but inccorect result coming:   SELECT t.GroupName AS GroupName, t.ApplicationName AS ApplicationName, t.UserName
 FROM UserApplication t
 WHERE $ApplicationName IS NULL OR $ApplicationName = '' OR t.ApplicationName = $ApplicationName OR $Username IS NULL OR $Username ='' 
 OR t.UserName = 'devendrat';

Comment: When I passed vales 'devendrat' in username variable then it showing me rows for other users also that should not be happened.... my scenarion is if do not pass values then it show all values from table while if i pass any values to application or username then it should value wrto that value only

Comment: please help its very urgent and i dont know mysql

Comment: @KapilSingh . . . I'm pretty sure the logic in the `where` statement is correct.  You should modify your question and put the code you are using there.

Comment: I tried your code with 2 conditions but its not giving me desired result

Comment: When I ran your query without passing any values to the parameters then also its not returning me all the values from the table

Answer (score 0):

Your `@groupname` is probably not `''` but `null`. You don't need an `if` with that query

```
SELECT t.GroupName AS GroupName, t.GroupName AS ApplicationName, t.UserName
FROM UserApplication t
WHERE t.GroupName = @groupname 
OR @groupname IS NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, MySQL doesn't support default parameters. There are several StackOverflow postings about this. So it looks like you'll have to pass a value for `@groupName`.

You can combine the two queries like this:

```
SELECT t.GroupName AS GroupName, t.GroupName AS ApplicationName, t.UserName
FROM UserApplication t
WHERE @groupname = '' OR t.GroupName = @groupname;
```

Or if you'll be using `NULL` for `@groupName` (which I'd recommend for something like this):

```
SELECT t.GroupName AS GroupName, t.GroupName AS ApplicationName, t.UserName
FROM UserApplication t
WHERE @groupname IS NULL OR t.GroupName = @groupname;
```

Comment: Is the `groupName` variable truly prefixed with `@`? If this is a procedure and the variable is just `groupName` it will conflict with the column of the same name. See [Local Variable Scope and Resolution in the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/local-variable-scope.html) for more information.

Comment: ya its truly prefix with @

Comment: How are you calling this? Is it from MySQL or another language such as PHP? The queries in all the answers are generally correct, so maybe there's a problem in how it's called. Note that MySQL doesn't support default variable values, so you can't just *not* pass a value; you have to pass null or blank.

Comment: Actually I am using this query in a report... I am calling it directly as a script only